# onActivityResult need help getting image

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-bitmap, onactivityresult

I'm trying to get an image by starting an `Intent` to select from the photo gallery using `startActivityForResult` and by overriding `onActivityResult`. I don't know why, but when I select an image and try to draw it on my screen, nothing happens. I'm able to select the image, and then that's it.

I searched for answers but couldn't find anything that helped. There doesn't seem to be much that I can try to fix this problem. I believe I've implemented everything correctly. This is also my first time trying this though so I could be wrong. I've overrided the `onActivityResult` to get a bitmap and set a bitmap variable from another class with it when I call `getGalleryImage()`.

Starting the Intent from my GameView class:

```
MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) context;

public void getGalleryImage() {
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    gallery.setType("image/*");
    String[] mimeTypes = { "image/png" };
    gallery.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
    activity.startActivityForResult(gallery, 1);
}
```

Override Method in MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == MainActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            final Uri uri = data.getData();
            InputStream in;
            try {
                in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                final Bitmap selected_img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                view.setSelectedImage(selected_img);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "An error occured!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You didn't pick an image!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the image and draw it to my screen. What's happening is I select the image after the intent opens, and then nothing. It goes back to my activity and nothing seems to be drawing at all.

Comment: Are you sure that `view` is actually visible on-screen? `BitmapFactory` can return null. Have you checked to see if it is? Have you debugged to check the value of the returned `Uri`, and to see if it's actually reaching the `try` block?

Comment: Yes, my view and all seems to work fine until I select an image and the intent goes away. At that point the view stops drawing and my app becomes unresponsive but doesn't crash.

Comment: Well, that's a little different than "nothing happens". I'm not familiar with any `View` that has a `setSelectedImage()` method, so I'm not sure what you're using there. The first thing i would do is to check if the `Bitmap selected_img` is null. If not, then your image retrieval is working just fine, and the problem would be in that `view`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems like your `View.setSelectedImage()` comes from a custom class, you might want to try trying to draw the `Bitmap` on `ImageView` first to see if it works.

Use `ImageView` instead and call `ImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` from within `onActivityResult()`. And make sure decoded bitmap isn't too large as it can cause your app to stutter and you might want to try [loading large bitmap efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap).

Also, update your `getGalleryImage()` method to this:

```
public void getGalleryImage() {
    final Intent galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to provide a provider from android version 7 (nougat)

First Set provider in manifest

```
</application>
    <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>

  </application>
```

Next define a xml file path named filepaths inside xml folder in resource :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Next call intent to pick image   :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
String[] mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/png"};
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

in your onactivity  result :

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Uri selectedImage = null;

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    selectedImage = data.getData();
                    InputStream in;
                    try {
                        in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                        final Bitmap selected_img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                        yourimageview.setImageBitmap(selected_img);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(this, "An error occured!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense. Firstly, they're not serving up any files, nor are they providing any file `Uri`s for external apps to write to. Secondly, your example isn't even using the `FileProvider` anywhere. All you've done is set one up in the manifest.

Comment: Adding a `<provider>` seems to make my app crash on start up.

Comment: @ChristianWaldmann i have added provider according to androidx configuration. if you are not using androidx , please change the provider according to support configuration and try.

Comment: Also you have to add the provider inside the application tag